# Cancelling Meeting/Appointment using EWS java API

Tags: ewsjavaapi

I'm new to EWS Java api, So I'm developing a android application in which one module is to cancel the meeting/appointment. Did search a lot for online help & it dint work out and nor did i get much help! So, please someone help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you having difficulty retrieving the Appointment? Are you able to retrieve the Appointment from Exchange, but unable to cancel it?

Comment: @user1017413- I'm unable to use the API Appointment.bind(mService, new ItemId("????")); from where do you get this ItemId?. So, I'm unable to retrieve the appointments.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you look at the JWebServices for Exchange.
It supports Android, which looks good to me, when I was trying to figure out your problem a few years ago.

[Cancel meeting example](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices/tutorial/cancelmeeting.html)

Comment: @Paul-I have already tried with it! It still doesn't work because its a proprietary library n EWS Java API is an open source.So, moreover its customized